# Cannot convert data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, nvarchar

get this error to the `txtNum.Text` i dont know what to do i already tried the

`Convert.ToInt32` and `SqlDbType.Int` but it doesnt work please help me

the total has a $ sign in it maybe that's the problem. the Total's DataType is Decimal

```
com = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Orders(
                        OrderDate, 
                        Username, 
                        FirstName, 
                        LastName, 
                        Address, 
                        Phone, 
                        Total, 
                        HasBeenShipped
                    ) 
                    VALUES(
                        GetDate(),
                        @p5, 
                        @p1, 
                        @p2, 
                        @p3, 
                        @p4, 
                        @p6,
                        'false'
                    )", con2);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Label2.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtFname.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TxtLname.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TxtAdd.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Convert.ToInt32(TxtNum.Text));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", lblTotal.Text);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is the type of `Total` is it `varchar` in database ?

Comment: im getting the error to the Phone not Total

Comment: PhoneNumber should be varchar in database. Just check if it is `varchar` because in that case you can simply do `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TxtNum.Text);`, without converting it to int

Comment: Please give the error message you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lblTotal` is formatted as a currency then you can use:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Decimal.Parse(lblTotal.Text,NumberStyles.Currency));
```

Obviously it will throw an exception if it's *not* a valid currency value - you'd need to decide what to do in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the last field `HasBeenShipped` is a bit datatype in the database.
If this is the case then pass 0 (the numeric value) for it not 'false' (a string)

Moreover it is the parameter `@p6` that contains the value for the field `Total` and thus it is this parameter that should be converted to a number, while the parameter `@p4` could be a string if the field `Phone` is a `NVarChar`

```
com = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Orders 
             (OrderDate, Username, FirstName, LastName, Address, Phone, Total, HasBeenShipped)
       VALUES(GetDate(), @p5,      @p1,       @p2,      @p3,     @p4,   @p6,   0)", con2);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Label2.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtFname.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TxtLname.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TxtAdd.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TxtNum.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Convert.ToInt32(lblTotal.Text));
```

**EDIT** Following your comment below, if the `lblTotal.Text` contains the currency symbol then you cannot convert directly to an integer with Convert.ToInt32, you should use `decimal.TryParse`

```
decimal totalValue
decimal.TryParse(lblTotal.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, 
                 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out totalValue);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", totalValue);
```

Comment: the total has a $ sign in it maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Of course, this is not directly convertible in an integer, but this leads to: what is the datatype of the field Total? It is an integer or a decimal?

Comment: the datatype is decimal

Comment: it works but when i check the sql server the value of total is 0.00 when i have a value in lblTotal.Text

Comment: The conversion could fail resulting in a zero value for the variable if the currency label and the decimal sign are not the one used in your culture, In that case you need to pass an appropriate CultureInfo. You say that there is a $ in the label, what is the exact value and what is your culture?